# Windows Service Won't Start. Error 1067 - attaching Debugger fixes Issue - why?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-4.5

I have created a windows service in C# .Net 4.5, and for some reason it will not start on my machine.
I have placed a Debugger.Launch(), and it breaks fine and works well afterwards, but without the debugger I get error 1067, and it does not start.

Might be related - I upgraded the code from .Net  3.5, maybe some differences are causing this error?

and I have a Windows 7 64 bit.

Update:

I found the reason it is not working - there was an exception thrown - FileNotFound to be more specific and Enviorment.Exit in the catch,
 but so my question wouldn't be so useless - 
I ask why attaching the debbuger fixed the issue? why didn't it throw the exception?

Comment: Check the event viewer's Windows Applications log.

Comment: Found the reason it wasn't working - there was an exception thrown and an Enviorment.Exit in the catch - but I still don't get why the debugger didn't show it.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: I Was looking for a file in a path that didn't exist so FileNotFoundException